# How to Convert Instances from NominalToBinary

Tags: java, weka

Is there any existing Class in Weka to convert Instances from Nominal To Binary that has the following input and output format.

Input Instances Format and Data

```
 |Fruits|Test|Price|
 ------------------------------
 |Apple |0   |5    |
 |Banana|1   |7    |
 |Orange|1   |4    |
```

Output Instances Format and Data

```
 |Apple|Banana|Orange|Test|Price|
 ------------------------------
 | 1   |  0   | 0    |0   |5    |
 | 0   |  1   | 0    |1   |7    |
 | 0   |  0   | 1    |1   |4    |
```

Or I have to write my own code. What is the easiest way? I guess the class NominalToBinary in Weka is not suitable for this case.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the NominalToBinary filter is exactly the filter that does that:

```
Instances instances = null; // Your Instances object
NominalToBinary nominalToBinary = new NominalToBinary();
nominalToBinary.setInputFormat(instances);
String[] options = {"-R", "15"}; // the index(es) of the nominal feature(s)
nominalToBinary.setOptions(options);
Instances newInstances = Filter.useFilter(instances, nominalToBinary);
```

Comment: It is only when class is Nominal. Also, option should be String[] options = {"-A"}; In my case Class is Price, which is numeric.

Comment: The filter is not supervised and it is performed on the attributes you specify. In your case the attribute is 'Fruits' and the index can be "first". The Price attribute has nothing to do with this.

Comment: `String[] options = {"-R", "15"};`, What does this line do? Can you please explain it with respect to the question that had been asked?

Answer (score 1):

I think @AndreyF is correct. I'm using the GUI, so I'll show the commands from there rather than the java.

We'll start with this file:

```
@relation stackexchange1

@attribute Fruits {Apple,Banana,Orange}
@attribute Test numeric
@attribute Price numeric

@data
Apple,0,5
Banana,1,7
Orange,1,4
```

and use this filter:

```
NominalToBinary -R first
```

That gives us this file, which looks like what you want:

```
@relation stackexchange1-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToBinary-Rfirst

@attribute Fruits=Apple numeric
@attribute Fruits=Banana numeric
@attribute Fruits=Orange numeric
@attribute Test numeric
@attribute Price numeric

@data
1,0,0,0,5
0,1,0,1,7
0,0,1,1,4
```

or we could use

```
NominalToBinary -N -R first
```

which gives the first three attributes as nominal (with t,f rather than 0,1)

```
@relation stackexchange1-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToBinary-N-Rfirst

@attribute Fruits=Apple {f,t}
@attribute Fruits=Banana {f,t}
@attribute Fruits=Orange {f,t}
@attribute Test numeric
@attribute Price numeric

@data
t,f,f,0,5
f,t,f,1,7
f,f,t,1,4
```